# Fields only from the first paragraph

Tags: views, paragraphs

I have a node type with paragraphs.

In a view I need to get fields from these paragraphs. But only from the first paragraph of every node.

In the view I have a relationship to the field which references the paragraph. So I get all the fields from the paragraph.

But now I get the fields from all paragraphs and I need only the ones from the first paragraph. There's no option to set the output to only the first paragraph.

Comment: are you sure in the view editing that field  there is not a "MULTIPLE FIELD SETTINGS" ?

Comment: The multiple field settings I could have, when using the whole paragraph. Paragraphs a multiple. I use the fields from multiple paragraphs.